# Issue with Mockito.Any for overloaded methods

Tags: mockito

I have two methods in my Java class as below
Method 1:

```
public ResponseEntity<T> callMethod(String param1,Map<String, String> param2, Object param3,HttpMethod param4,Class<T> param5)
```

Method 2

```
public ResponseEntity<T> callMethod(Map<String, String> param1, Object param2,
            HttpMethod param3, Map<String, ?> param4,
            final Class<T> param5) {
```

I have written a unit test case where when i try to call the method as below

```
callMethod(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),
                eq(ServiceResponse.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity)
```

it fails with the below error

reference to callMethod is ambiguous

> both method callMethod
> (java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,B,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>,java.lang.Class)
> and method
> callMethod(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,B,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.Class)
> match

How can this be resolved. There are many unit test cases and i want to fix the class than the unit test cases. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put types in the `any()` like `any(MyClass.class)` there are also some built in ones. If you want to call your first method you can use the `anyString()` and `anyMap()` ones.

```java
callMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), eq(ServiceResponse.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity)
```

Comment: THank you...My Base class has so many consumers. It is kind of common class. So do you see anyway this can be addressed in the java class so that the unit test classes written by so many consumers need not change?

Comment: You could change the production code so the methods have a different number of parameters or simply change the name of the method. Anything that would remove the ambiguity, but if you have more then one definition of a method with the same number of parameters, you need to help mockito know which one to mock.